# Magento 1.7 - can't insert image in wysiwyg

Tags: image, magento, wysiwyg, magento-1.7

I have a local install of Magento 1.7.  I installed it with the sample data.  I have made no changes to it - it's the default install.  There are two (probably related) problems:

1. If I look at any of the static blocks created with the sample data, none of the images show in the wysiwyg editor.  It just shows a placeholder images that says "skin image".  The images do show properly in the front end.
2. If I create a new static block, and try to insert an image by clicking on the 'insert/edit image' icon of the editor, the image will upload, but clicking 'insert image' will not insert the image into the editor.

I googled on the images not showing in the editor and there are tons of posts about it on versions 1.4, none of which have worked for me in 1.7.  I would have thought it would be corrected by 1.7.

Also, I do have an old install of 1.6 on the same server that I played around with about 6 months ago and it does not have this problem.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Thanks, 
Mickey

Comment: Ugh.  Disregard the second item.  I'm a moron.  Still looking for help with the first item though.

Answer (score 1):

For issue No.1 download the sample database from http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/installing-the-sample-data-for-magento

and put the images in respective folder, and clear the cache.

**EDIT**

Open any static block and click on Show/Hide Editor button and you will see that there is variable passed in SRC like "{{skin url='images/media/electronics_cellphones.jpg}}", which is create the dynamic links based on the base URL of your site. That's why in admin section it's not showing the image.

Comment: Ummm...I did.  The images are showing correctly on the front end.  They do not show in the wysiwyg editor.

Comment: Sorry.  I still don't understand why it's not working.  That is exactly the SRC that I'm seeing.  The base URL is set in config > Web > Unsecure. I'm not using SSL as it's just on my local computer, and I'm accessing the site through the URL, not the IP.  What else am I missing?

Comment: The reason the Skin Image placeholder is showing is because it will change based on the skin that skin that is being displayed at the front end. If you were to change one of these images (or add another one in) via the WYSIWYG interface, it would display

Comment: Ok.  Still don't get why the wysiwyg editor wouldn't automatically just use the path from the skin that is currently set. But whatever.  Moving on.  Thanks for taking the time to reply Arya and CCBlackburn.